# limit for $a_n=\frac{n}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the limit for $$a_n=\frac{n}{3^n}$$ using the sandwich theorem. I know that
$$\frac{n}{3^n}\ge0\ \overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow 0$$
For my upper boundary I cannot say $$\frac{n}{3^n}\le\frac{2^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow 0$$

because $n\le2^n$ is not correct for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Am I correct? What could I come up with instead?

Comment: But $n$ **is** less than or equal to $2^{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. And also, it is irrelevant if you are taking the limit as $n \to \infty$. You just need $2^{n} \ge n$ for all $n > N$.

Comment: for which $n$ is it equal?

Comment: Using the binomial theorem, $$3^n=(1+2)^n\ge 2n(n-1)$$And therefore $$\frac{n}{3^n}\le \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$.

Comment: @MarkViola I wrote the term with the binominal theorem and expanded the sum to look, if i could find anything similar. But I did not... Would you point out how exactly one receives $$(1+2)^n\ge 2n(n-1)$$

Comment: Is it that one just expands the sum and picks a few, but not all the terms from that expansion to ensure one has something definately smaller (or equal to) $\frac{n}{3^n}$? That would make sense to me, altough I still do not see how you get $2n(n-1)$ even having written out the summation

Comment: @MarkViola for example $$(1+2)^n\ge 1 +2n$$ is also correct following the binomial theorem, but it does not give me the right limit if I then say $$\frac{n}{3^n}\le \frac{n}{1 +2n}$$

Comment: @PhilippWulff Yes, that bound does not suffice.  But that is not relevant.  The bound I gave does suffice.

Answer (score 0):

it is correct. x is linear curve; $2^x$ is exponential like curve which grows much faster than linear.

Another way, apply l'Hospital rule, limit value =$\frac{1}{3^n \ln 3} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

See if sequence is treated as function, and function tend to some limit then that sequence also tend to same limit. So if you find limit of $x$/$3^{x}$..as $x$ tends to $\infty$,then that is limit of your sequence and if you know L'hospital rule then you will easily get the answer is $0$..